# Swift-Xcode UILabel inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard

So here, I have problems about the UIScrollView.

I have a UIScrollView that manage scrolling vertically my videos on my program. I would like, on videos, add at the bottom left a text. I add a View inside my ScrollView in order to then put labels texts. But everything is shifted when I try (for example) to place the label with the constraint center X and Y, the label is found on the top left.

Can you enlighten me on what I forgot? Thank you.

My storyboard : https://gyazo.com/70945dc627a5265e12fff681f4415df5

Simulator : (look label at the top left) https://gyazo.com/84b24b1c9560ef46418ebc08a7711a70

And my contentView has constraints 0 for 4 sides...!

Comment: Do the labels move with the scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints of the contentView aren't enough, you have to add constraints for the size. Keep in mind that you are working inside a ScrollView.

Comment: Thx for your answer, When I add my 2 size constraints to my contentView it gives me the same result. I think I'll look in detail constraints but I do not understand where is the concern.

Comment: Try to give different `backgroundColor` to all the elements (scrollView, contentView and label). Usually It is helpful to see what happen.

Comment: Yeah thanks I managed to do what I wanted it was enough to superimpose the two views and just put my view over alpha 0 :)

Comment: If you have found my answer and my comment helpful, consider to upvote them, thankyou!